# When calling a python script via the terminal, ImportError

Tags: python

When calling a python script from within Pycharm my script runs successfully. However when I call the same script via my terminal I get an import error:

```
Macs-MacBook:src macuser$ python ./run_events.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_events.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functions import return_ga_data
  File "/Users/macuser/PycharmProjects/ops-google-extract/src/functions.py", line 2, in <module>
    import connect
  File "/Users/macuser/PycharmProjects/ops-google-extract/src/connect.py", line 4, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
ImportError: cannot import name 'ServiceAccountCredentials'
```

I am not using an environment. Also I'm using python 3.7.

All my python scripts are in the same directory. My terminal's pwd is the same directory.

Tried:
Tried calling the script with `python3 ./run_events.py` but I get the same result.

Per an SO post about paths I added this to the top of connect.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/macuser/PycharmProjects/ops-google-extract/src/functions.py')
```

I still got the same result.

Why can I run the file without an import error from within my IDE but not via the terminal when using `./run_events.py`?

Comment: try to set your path, something like `PYTHONPATH=. python run_events.py` or whatever path is your base one. My guess is `PYTHONPATH=/Users/macuser/PycharmProjects`

Comment: Hi David. You mean I write that at the top of my script or as I'm calling it? Can you clarify your recommendations

Comment: so in the terminal execute the following cmd: `PYTHONPATH=/Users/macuser/PycharmProjects python run_events.py` (not sure what's the exact path though)

Comment: adding 3.7 seemed to get it going `PYTHONPATH=/Users/macuser/PycharmProjects python3.7 run_events.py`
I don't know if adding the path was a necessary part too or not, but it's going now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: _I am not using an environment._ Why? You probably should.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have python 2 installed as well?  Type python --version in the terminal and see what you get?  My guess is Pycharm might be configured to use python 3 while your default python in terminal is python 2, so your python 2 is lacking those modules that was installed for python 3.  So when you execute your script in the terminal it's using python 2.  If that's the case you can try,

```
py -3 ./myscript.py
```